# Child object not following default camera in SceneKit

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit

In a project, I have attached a `SCNPlane` to the default camera provided as `allowsCameraControl` is set to `true`, like so:

```
scnView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(plane)
```

Then the plane is placed right in front of the default camera:

```
plane.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)
```

When I debug the scene though, it shows the plane at the correct position, initially. However, the plane does not stay in front of the camera but rather at the initial position when the default cameras position is altered via user touch input.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause the misunderstanding here?

Comment: If I remember correctly, as soon as the camera is moved by gestures, an internal camera object is created and used to perform the movement, so your object will not be moved, because it stays with it's original camera. This is due this special allowsCameraControl property. Try to disable this property (set to false) and move the camera alernatively. (on github you can find examples on moving/rotating objects with gestures, that do not relay on the allowsCameraControl - i.Ex: https://github.com/gadsden/SceneKit-Quaternion-Rotations)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of that and explicitly wanna make use of the default camera created via allowsCameraControl, as it is very good. I thought attaching an object to that camera would work the same way but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that at the time

```
scnView.pointOfView?.addChild(plane)
```

was executed, the actual poV of the scene was still the old camera and not the generated one by `allowsCameraControl`. poV switches to the generated one as soon as the user makes first touch input.